# How to tell 0/1 from false/true with NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I need to deal with JSON data with arbitrary structures in iOS.

However, `NSJSONSerialization` convert true/false value into `NSNumber`.

So my question is, how can I tell when a `NSNumber` is converted from a boolean value `true`/`false`, as apposed to actual number `0`/`1`?

*Note: I am aware of `[NSNumber numberWithBool]`, but here, I want to figure out when it's appropriate to call it. I'm also aware that writing my own parser solves this problem, but I want to make sure there isn't a easier solution before I go done that route.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is:

```
if ([parsedValue isKindOfClass [NSNumber class]] &&
    strcmp([parsedValue objCType], @encode(char)) == 0) {
    // parsedValue is converted from 'true' or 'false' in JSON.
}
```

One weird thing is `NSJSONSerielization` sets `objCType` of a boolean value to `@encode(char)` instead of `@encode(BOOL)`.

Comment: `BOOL` **is** `signed char`. But `@encode(bool)` is indeed different. See http://nshipster.com/type-encodings/

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can't know if an NSNumber "was" a boolean. But no matter call boolValue and if it was boolean value you will get the right value. If it was a number you get true for all value except 0.